# unable to update gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help ,i have added update/edit command button in gridview so to update data in my sql server database but am unable to do it. Data is not updated in database .
======code for onrowupdate========================================
protected void gRowUpdate(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Books b = null;
    b = new Books();
    DataTable dt=null;
    GridView g = (GridView)sender;
    try
    {   dt=new DataTable();
        b = new Books();
        b.author = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Author"));
        b.bookID = Convert.ToInt32(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("BookID"));
        b.title = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Title"));
        b.price = Convert.ToDouble(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Price"));
        // b.rec = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Date_of_reciept"));
        b.ed = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        b.bill = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        b.cre_by = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        b.src = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        b.pages = Convert.ToInt32(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        b.pub = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        b.mod_by = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        b.remark = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        //  b.year = Convert.ToString(g.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Edition"));
        b.updatebook(b);
        g.EditIndex = -1;
        dt = b.GetAllBooks();
        g.DataSource = dt;
        g.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        b = null;
    }

}
===================My stored procedure for update book able to update database by exec in sqlserver mgmt studio==========================
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_updatebook]
@bookid bigint,
@author varchar(50),
@title varchar(50),
@price bigint,
@src_equisition varchar(50),
@bill_no varchar(50),
@publisher varchar(50),
@pages bigint,
@remark varchar(50),
@edition varchar(50),
@created_by varchar(50),
@modified_by varchar(50)
/*@date_of_reciept datetime,
@year_of_publication datetime*/
AS
declare 
 @modified_on datetime

set @modified_on=getdate()

UPDATE books

SET

author=@author, 
title=@title, 
price=@price,

src_equisition=@src_equisition,
bill_no=@bill_no,
publisher=@publisher,
/*Date_of_reciept=@date_of_reciept,*/
pages=@pages,
remark=@remark,
edition=@edition,
/*Year_of_publication=@year_of_publication,*/

created_by=@created_by,
modified_on=@modified_on,
modified_by=@modified_by

WHERE bookid=@bookid
========================class library function for update====================

```
    public void updatebook(Books b)
    {
        DataAccess dbAccess = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        try
        {
            dbAccess = new DataAccess();
            cmd = dbAccess.GetSQLCommand("usp_updatebook", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@bookid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.bookID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@author", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.author;
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.title;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Money).Value = b.price;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@publisher", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.pub;
          // cmd.Parameters.Add("@year_of_publication", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =Convert.ToDateTime( b.year);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@src_equisition", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.src;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@bill_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.bill;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@remark", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.remark;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pages", SqlDbType.Int).Value = b.pages;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@edition", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.ed;
           // cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_of_reciept", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(b.rec);
            // cmd.Parameters.Add("@created_on", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(b.cre_on);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@created_by", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.cre_by;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_on", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(b.mod_on);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@modified_by", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = b.mod_by;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cmd.Connection != null && cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            dbAccess = null;
            cmd = null;
        }
```

## }

I have also tried to do update by following way
protected void gv1_updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView g = (GridView)sender;
            abc a = new abc();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {

```
            a.cd_Id = Convert.ToInt32(g.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
            //TextBox b = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("cd_id");
            TextBox c = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("cd_name");
            TextBox d = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("version");
            TextBox f = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("company");
            TextBox h = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("created_by");
            TextBox i = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("modified_by");

            //a.cd_Id = Convert.ToInt32(b.Text);
            a.cd_name = c.Text;
            a.ver = d.Text;
            a.comp = f.Text;
            a.cre_by = h.Text;
            a.mod_by = i.Text;
            a.updateDigi(a);
            g.EditIndex = -1;
            dt = a.GetAllDigi();
            g.DataSource = dt;
            g.DataBind();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            dt = null;
            a = null;
            g = null;
        }



    }
```

=================== but have error of Index out of range exception=========

please do reply,thanxs in advance

Answer (score 1):

The IndexOutOfRangeException is probably due to this code:

```
        a.cd_Id = Convert.ToInt32(g.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
        TextBox c = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("cd_name");
        TextBox d = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("version");
        TextBox f = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("company");
        TextBox h = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("created_by");
        TextBox i = (TextBox)g.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("modified_by");
```

More precisely the part where the indexing is occurring. Are you sure that you have 9 Cells
(indexes 0 to 8) ?

Comment: thanks for replying i tried it by changing the index but still have the same error.Can You just paste a small eg code for gridview update.In the first method above no error occurs but database is not updated. Actually no values are read from gridview cells. Need it urgently Have it as a part of final year project. thank you very much for replying